# Convert byte array to jpeg in grayscale

Tags: c#, image, jpeg

I have a simple Byte array representing an image in gray scale (value come from 0 to 255)

There is an example :

```
Byte[] sample = new Byte[16] {
    55 ,0  ,0  ,255,
    12 ,255,75 ,255,
    255,150,19 ,255,
    42 ,255,78 ,255 };
```

I want to save this in jpeg format but I don't know how I can do this.

I've try 2 ways but it doesn't work. I think my byte array is not right formatted but I don't know how to do.

I have tried this :

```
TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Bitmap));
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)tc.ConvertFrom(sample);
bmp.Save(myPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

And this :

```
MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream(sample);
str.Position = 0;
using (Image image = Image.FromStream(str))
{
    image.Save(myPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's valid JPEG data?  Your use of a stream seems like it should do what you want if that data is JPEG data.

Comment: The data isn't an image file itself but an array of pixel data, so you must create a Bitmap, set the pixels to the colors you have (using SetPixel or LockBits) and then save the bitmap as jpeg.

Comment: I expect that somewhere you need to tell your library that your data is  grayscale (i.e. one component).

Comment: @Gusman I've try the solution below to create a BItmap but it did not work for me. How can I simply copy my pixels to a Bitmap ? I think I missed something, I did not set the height/width for my image so I wonder How it can works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With all your indications, I finally find a way :

```
public static void SaveByteArryToJpeg(string imagePath, Byte[] data, int width, int height)
{
    if (width * height != data.Length)
        throw new FormatException("Size does not match");

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);

    for (int r = 0; r < height; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < width; c++)
        {
            Byte value = data[r * width + c];
            bmp.SetPixel(c, r, Color.FromArgb(value, value, value));
        }
    }

    bmp.Save(imagePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: Glad you got it working :) Be ware that SetPixel is extremely slow, if you want a fast conversion check the documentation for LockBits, it will lock the bitmap image data as a pointer so you can assign the data directly just copying the array.

Comment: I will probably have to work on many images, I will take a look. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
BitmapImage photo = byteToImage(byte[] sample)
```

this functionto convert byte to BitmapImage

```
public BitmapImage byteToImage(byte[] buffer)
{

 using(var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
 {
   var image = new BitmapImage();
   image.BeginInit();
   image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
   image.StreamSource =  ms;
   image.EndInit();
 }

 return image;
}
```

and then `byteToImage` will return an image, so you can save.

Hopefully this can help you

Comment: I've try this but when I execute `image.EndInit();`, a NotSupportedException is received : "Could not locate the image processing component which is suitable to complete this operation".